# While Loop with Scanner.hasNextInt() skips last item

Tags: java

I was practicing using Scanner and I've encountered an strange occurance and i would like some help from the community to understand this.
I've a text file with the following numbers

```
1,2,3,9
5,9
3
```

reading the text file with the following java code

```
fsc = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
fsc.useDelimiter(",");
while (fsc.hasNextLine()) {
    while (fsc.hasNextInt()){
        System.out.print(fsc.nextInt() + ","); 
    }
    System.out.println();
    fsc.nextLine(); 
}
```

and the results always skips the last number.

```
1,2,3,
5,
3,
```

How do i make it not ignore the last item?

Edit: Some solutions calls for splinting them to an array and converting the strings to integer however I would like to explore using `Scanner.nextInt()` instead

Edited 2: I'm so sorry seems many misunderstood the question. What i meant was missing is the last digit of each line is missing!

Comment: try removing fsc.nextLine();

Comment: @FedericoCiuffardi it just goes into a infinite loop

Comment: try to do with do/while to inner loop. I am not sure because I didn't write down but maybe your code gets the first element of the last line and since it has no next Int it just skips it..

Comment: @Weiest but did you remove the while (fsc.hasNextLine()) { ?

Comment: @FedericoCiuffardi now it only does the first line.

Comment: Instead of using `hasNextLine` use `while(fsc.nextLine() != null) maybe?

Comment: emm if you leave your code as it is in your question and add a  System.out.print(fsc.nextInt() + ","); before the  System.out.println(); does it works?

Comment: @FedericoCiuffardi that throws a InputMismatchException

Comment: so maybe it's becouse it's waiting for a ',' after the number and the last one does not a have it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you removed the standard delimiters, i.e. linefeeds. You need

```
fsc.useDelimiter("[ ,\r\n]");
```

So this becomes

```
fsc = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
fsc.useDelimiter("[ ,\r\n]");
while (fsc.hasNextLine()) {
    while (fsc.hasNextInt()){
        System.out.print(fsc.nextInt() + ","); 
    }
    System.out.println();
    if (fsc.hasNextLine())
        fsc.nextLine(); 
}
```

Comment: That works! Thank you but i'm just wondering what's the difference between using fsc.useDelimiter(",|\r\n"); vs fsc.useDelimiter("[ ,\r\n]");

I used the former and it just printed all in one line.

Comment: "[ ,\r\n]" is like an or of the characters inside and  " ,\r\n" is that exact sequence

Answer (score 1):

Just add one condition to check new line,

[image]

Comment: Hi sorry! I noticed many misunderstood the question, i was referring the last integer of each line is always missing

Comment: @Weiest you are using wrong deliminator. Use `"[ ,\r]"`